# Update Panel, Update method won't update a Control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a repeater formed as a Html Table. The preview is about like this:

```
| No |    Name   |    Status   |
--------------------------------
| 1. | Process A | In Progress |
| 2. | Process B | In Progress |
| 3. | Process C | In Progress |
| 4. | Process D | In Progress |
...
| n. | Process N | In Progress |
--------------------------------
```

I placed the repeater inside the Update Panel.

When I click a button, the form will call such a Send process function. 
The function will loop for each row and set the Status text from "In Progress" to "Sent".
Suppose the process is about 2 seconds
I want to update the Status text in Repeater via UpdatePanel.Update() after the Status text is assigned, but my problem is the Status wont updated.
It's updated after the function finished.

The send function is like this:

```
protected void btnSend_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptData.Items) 
        {
            UpdatePanel upnlStatus = (UpdatePanel)item.FindControl("upnlStatus");
            Literal litStatus = (Literal)item.FindControl("litStatus");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            litStatusText = "Sent";
            upnlStatus.Update();                
        }
    }
```

My question is what is the best method to do this things?
Is the Update Panel support this kind of realtime update? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern of the AsyncPostback of a update panel is

1. Client make request
2. Server do a task
3. Client is updated

So, it wait that 2 is completed before doing 3. You cannot trigger the update of the client from the execution of a task on the server because the Server process cease to exist on the server between each AsyncPostback. The whole page is recreated from the view-state between each AsyncPostback.

To do what you want to do, you need to start the task Asyncroniously and retrieve the result later. The must common way of doing this is with [Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398898.aspx). Also check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163393.aspx).

Comment: Thanks @DavRob60 :)
But is it possible to do this without WebService? I've heard about Async method in C#. Can I do this partial rendering via C# Async server method? Thanks

Comment: @WillyLazuardi This is a huge simplification, but "Async server method" are parts of Web services. It would take to much time to explain in in the details.